# Intercept WCF request with HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, wcf, httphandler

I would like to be able to redirect a request to a WCF service to a duplicate WCF service on another server - **is it possible to pass on the HttpContext to another server?**

*Using an HTTPHandler I am able to take the request from the context and extract from this the actual request object, then send this to another service - this is extra effort if I am able to pass along the whole context (which would include the original SOAP envelope).*

-EDIT: The reason for this is that our Client has only one Url to use for multiple WCF services, this Url can only be pointed at port 80 on IIS. One of their Clients has specified that their solution must live on a separate server to any other Clients solution. The environment has a load balancer which holds the SSL certificate, so externally the Client of the WCF service communicates with the load balancer over SSL, but the load balancer talks to the server to port 80 over normal HTTP. I am unable to affect this environment configuration.

Comment: I dont think HttpContext is serializable...so it will be diffcult to pass whole context object to another server......But why you want to do this? explain your problem statement may be you will get better answer

Comment: Ok - thank you Viru - will try this

Comment: ok on another thought, may be you can try using binary serialization and serialize the whole http context object as bytes and send it to WCF service.. you service needs to have extra parameter which will hold array of bytes...In you WCF service you can deserialize the array of bytes to  HttpContext object

Comment: Thank you Viru - I was hoping for an easier mechanism, but if needs must!

Comment: It sounds like you want a reverse proxy. The URL Rewrite module for IIS can do that for you. So you can make a particular URL on the "main IIS server" end up as a request on another internal server.

Comment: may be you need wcf load balancer (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778575/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-III-Failover-Load-Balanci) or WCF proxy (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29775/WCF-Intermediate-Service-between-Client-and-Server)